# Change log of IIsExpress startup

Tags: c#, .net, logging, iis-express

I´m investigating performance issues on IIS Express, and why it´s taking so long to load the symbols.

During startup I can see things like:

> 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319:
>   DefaultDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled.

Question is:

Is it possible to modify that log to add some kind of timestamp, so that I know how much time each of the symbols are taking to load?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well, found out a way.

Not exactly to change the iis log, but did the job:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace

then enable the timestamp margin feature.

Took from here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/de2b2d1f-0f1a-4949-8a49-b2bda776535a/show-timestamp-in-output-window-on-debug?forum=visualstudiogeneral